# Обновить записи в sqlite3 по условию

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Хотел бы узнать, как с помощью `sqlite3` и python делать условия.

Например, есть таблица base:

```
id|Users|Balance
1 |User1|0
2 |User2|100
3 |User3|200
4 |User4|300
```

И нужно написать условие: если в колонке id есть 1, то к значению 0 в колонке Balance приплюсовать 100...

Comment: SQL: `update base set balance = balance + 100 where id = 1` Если делать в Python то литералы `100` и `1` лучше параметризировать

Comment: Если такого id в таблице не будет, то он не выдаст ошибку?

Comment: Нет, ошибки не будет, но и изменений никаких не будет. Т.е. новой строки не появится

Comment: Кстати неплохо было бы дополнить вопрос описанием того, что должно произойти если в таблице нет записи с `id = 1`